# Should multiple ec2 instances share an EFS or should code be downloaded to instance on spin-up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-codecommit, amazon-efs

I am playing around with the idea of having an Auto Scaling Group for my website that receives a lot of traffic.  I need each server to be running an identical webservice, so I have come up with several ideas to make this happen.

**Idea 1: Use Code Commit + User Data**

I will keep my webserver code in a git repo in CodeCommit.  Then, when my EC2 instances spin-up, they will install apache2, and then pull from the git repo.

**Idea 2: Use Elastic File System**

After a server spins up, it will mount to one central EFS that has my webserver code on it.  EC2 will install apache2 then use EFS to get the proper php files etc.

**Idea 3: Use AWS S3**

Like above with apache2, but then download webserver code from s3.

Which option is advised? Why?

Comment: Why don't you create an image of one of your working machines and use it in the launch configuration of the ASG?

Comment: Oh thats a really good idea.  is it easy to update those images? @Mahdi

Comment: Yes it is easy. I put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a reference machine which is used for creating images. Keep it updated with the latest version of your code and when you are happy with it, create an image out of it, update your launch configuration, and change the ASG configuration so that it uses it. You can then stop the reference machine and leave the job to the ASG instances.

Comment: For instances in the ASG that are all ready running, an update to the AMI will have no affect, correct?  Those instances will need to be terminated and re-deployed?

Comment: Correct. Running instances will not be affected. But the newly launched ones will be running on the new image.